# sentences with participial clauses

Tags: tense, usage, participles

Que1-When a subordinate clause employs the perfect participle (*having+past participle*) can we use present tenses in the main clause(*know,  has been worrying*)?

> 1) Having lived there, he KNOWS its climate very well.
>   2) Having broken his leg, he HAS BEEN WORRYING all night.

And Que2-
Can we write present perfect in place of perfect participle?

> 1) Having broken his leg, he went home. = He HAS BROKEN his leg and he went home.

I've read through some websites about perfect participle but got further confused.Please could you clarify my doubt?

Comment: Yes to your two questions, but your second example should read "He has broken his leg and **gone** home".

Comment: @BillJ ... I think OP is asking about transforming the participial clause into a finite clause with a time reference which agrees with the main clause: "He **had broken** his leg and he went home*.

Comment: Exactly, I need transformation of the
participial clause into a finite
clause with a time reference
which agrees with the main
clause.

Comment: @nandy So why give the example "He HAS BROKEN his leg and he went home"? I thought you were asking if it was okay. Btw, that example is a coordination of two independent clauses -- there is no single main clause.

Answer (score 2):

The "having +PP" construction sets the event in the past *relative to the main clause*, but the verb in the main clause can be present or past. Eg:

> Having not eaten all day, I'm very hungry. (= as I haven't eaten all day)
>
> Having not eaten all day, I was very hungry. (= as I hadn't eaten all day)

Comment: You mean "having+pp" all depends on the main clause whether it is in past or present. If the main clause in present then "having+pp" must in present and if the main clause in past then "having+pp" must in past right?

Comment: *Having always paid his taxes, he **will get** a full State Pension.* I think in practice *the "having +PP" construction sets the event in the past relative to **time of utterance***, but I stand ready to be corrrected on that point if need be. I can see problems interpreting, say, *Having not eaten all day, he will be hungry* (now?, very soon?, by tea-time tomorrow night?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd say the participial perfect designates a state **at** Reference Time, arising out of the 'nonevent' during a timespan running up to RT. *He will be hungry now* establishes a present RT (this is epistemic *will*) so the participial perfect is understood as *He has not eaten all day*. Your other two establish future RTs, so the ppl.pf is understood as "He will not have eaten all day".

Comment: @StoneyB: oic. Yes, it makes more sense to *PP designates a state **at** RT*, rather than an explicit reference to some ***prior*** activity. Then it's just a matter of identifying the relevant RT from context, rather that focusing on the specific verb tense.